# Unexpected '?>' when connecting to mySql database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I'm student. What's wrong? I do not see any errors..

```
 <?php
$db_username='root';
$db_password='';
$db_name='xyzim1';
$db_host='localhost';
try{
    $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name",$db_username,$db_password);   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation for handling exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

> Each `try` must have at least one corresponding `catch` or `finally` block.